# How to force a certain sorting of two .bib entries?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

So there are two articles I'm citing in a paper, here are their BibTeX entries:

```
@incollection{ShapiroSI,
    Author = {Stewart Shapiro},
    Booktitle = {Identity and Modality},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-21 01:26:30 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-21 01:27:50 +0000},
    Pages = {109 -- 145},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {Structure and Identity},
    Year = {2006}}

@incollection{ShapiroGI,
    Author = {Stewart Shapiro},
    Booktitle = {Identity and Modality},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-21 04:24:06 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-21 04:24:54 +0000},
    Pages = {164 -- 173},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {The Governance of Identity},
    Year = {2006}}
```

Now, the article titled "Structure and Identity" is actually first chronologically, and the article "Governance and Identity" is a response to an article criticizing "Structure and Identity". Given that, I want "Structure and Identity" to be listed as Shapiro 2006a (i.e., be sorted before "Governance and Identity") even though it comes after "Governance and Identity" alphabetically.

How can I accomplish this without adding extra information to the reference that gets printed (I don't want to, for instance, specify a month of publication; it's obviously fine to add more information to the .bib entry so long as this information isn't printed in my references section)?

**EDIT:** Here is a complete MWE, (you can find `phil_review.bst` [here](http://tedsider.org/latex/phil_review.bst))

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@incollection{ShapiroSI,
    Author = {Stewart Shapiro},
    Booktitle = {Identity and Modality},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-21 01:26:30 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-21 01:27:50 +0000},
    Pages = {109 -- 145},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {Structure and Identity},
    Year = {2006}}

@incollection{ShapiroGI,
    Author = {Stewart Shapiro},
    Booktitle = {Identity and Modality},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-21 04:24:06 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-21 04:24:54 +0000},
    Pages = {164 -- 173},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {The Governance of Identity},
    Year = {2006}}

\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{ShapiroSI} and another citation \citep{ShapiroGI}


\bibliographystyle{phil_review}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be very easy using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I don't doubt that but, unfortunately, I have to use BibTeX for various bureaucratic reasons.

Comment: What style are you using?  The `.bst` sets the rules, so it's helpful if you provide a complete minimal example.  (And don't forget that, as a last resort, you can fiddle with the `.bbl` right before your submission to the Powers That Be and put things in any order you want.)

Comment: @jon Ah good call, my knowledge of how BibTeX and the .bst's work is minimal at best, so I didn't realize to include the .bst. Will edit the question now to include that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old BibTeX trick works here.  We use

```
\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
```

to define a command that doesn't actually print anything.  Then we put it in the titles of the two `.bib` entries because they are the point at which we want to disambiguate.  Nothing gets printed, but BibTeX will now sort theses entries in an order you can force.  Here's a complete example, slightly changed from yours.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}% <-- allows the filecontents to be re-written each run.
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}

@incollection{ShapiroSI,
    Author = {Stewart Shapiro},
    Booktitle = {Identity and Modality},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-21 01:26:30 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-21 01:27:50 +0000},
    Pages = {109 -- 145},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {\noop{aaa}Structure and Identity},
    Year = {2006}}

@incollection{ShapiroGI,
    Author = {Stewart Shapiro},
    Booktitle = {Identity and Modality},
    Date-Added = {2014-01-21 04:24:06 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-01-21 04:24:54 +0000},
    Pages = {164 -- 173},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {\noop{zzz}The Governance of Identity},
    Year = {2006}}

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}     % <-- note this is set twice; here 
\bibpunct{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}  %     and in this line.

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{ShapiroSI} and another citation \citep{ShapiroGI}

\bibliographystyle{phil_review}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Note, if you prefer to keep the `\noop` ready to go because you may want to use it for multpile documents, the `@preamble` command for BibTeX is your friend.  You could add this to your `.bib` file:

```
@preamble{ "\providecommand{\noop}[1]{}" }
```

Comment: @NicholasHamilton -- Isn't it though?  (Wish I could say I first thought of it...)

Comment: Really very cool.

Comment: @Dennis -- Cheers!

Comment: Nice addition of the `@preamble` command, didn't know about that either!

Comment: @preamble is cool, I use it for doing subscripts and superscripts in the titles. ie, `@PREAMBLE{"\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\ensuremath{_\textnormal{#1}}}\newcommand{\super}[1]{\ensuremath{^\textnormal{#1}}}\newcommand{\bibmath}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}"}`