# Change order in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I would like to change the naming of some references and perhaps gain an understanding on how bibtex orders references.

These are my references

```
@article{nitaj06a,
  author    = {Abderrahmane Nitaj},
  title     = {Cryptanalysis of {RSA} with constrained keys},
  journal   = {IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  volume    = {2006},
  year      = {2006},
  pages     = {92},
  ee        = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/092},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
@article{nitaj06b,
  author    = {Abderrahmane Nitaj},
  title     = {Application of {ECM} to a {C}lass of {RSA} keys},
  journal   = {IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  volume    = {2006},
  year      = {2006},
  pages     = {235},
  ee        = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/235},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
@article{nitaj06c,
  author    = {Abderrahmane Nitaj},
  title     = {{RSA} and a higher degree {D}iophantine {E}quation},
  journal   = {IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  volume    = {2006},
  year      = {2006},
  pages     = {93},
  ee        = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/093},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

In the document produced by latex, nitaj06a, nitaj06b, nitaj06c are named as [Nit06b], [Nit06a], [Nit06c] respectively.

Is there a way to change the naming such that the referencing would correspond to nitaj06a, nitaj06b, nitaj06c for [Nit06a], [Nit06b], [Nit06c] respectively?

P.S. I think the alphabetical ordering of the title has something to do with this.

Comment: You can use the `key` field to tell bibtex how to sort an entry. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi @cfr, I think that is what I'm looking for. Can you spell it out in the answer? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I think it only works when you don't have author information. You could do this with `biblatex` if that's a possibility.

Comment: The `.bst` usually follows 'rules' for sorting for a reason; if the rule is 'alphabetical by title when author and year are the same', I recommend you stick with it.  However, I recently answered a [similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160195/8528) that might prove helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

If `biblatex` is an option, you can specify the `sortname` explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{some.bib}
@article{nitaj06a,
  author    = {Abderrahmane Nitaj},
  title     = {Cryptanalysis of {RSA} with constrained keys},
  journal   = {IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  volume    = {2006},
  year      = {2006},
  pages     = {92},
  ee        = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/092},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de},
  sortname      =   {nitaj06a}
}
@article{nitaj06b,
  author    = {Abderrahmane Nitaj},
  title     = {Application of {ECM} to a {C}lass of {RSA} keys},
  journal   = {IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  volume    = {2006},
  year      = {2006},
  pages     = {235},
  ee        = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/235},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de},
  sortname      =   {nitaj06b}
}
@article{nitaj06c,
  author    = {Abderrahmane Nitaj},
  title     = {{RSA} and a higher degree {D}iophantine {E}quation},
  journal   = {IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive},
  volume    = {2006},
  year      = {2006},
  pages     = {93},
  ee        = {http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/093},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de},
  sortname      =   {nitaj06c}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{some}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Reference with <code>biblatex</code>]

Comment: If possible, I'll like to stick with BibTex. But thanks for your answer. +1 for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Citations can appear in the order you referenced them or in alphabetical order. See the natbib options [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib).

Alternatively, you can use the alpha bibliography style, or one of others listed on the same wikibooks page or [here](http://nodonn.tipido.net/bibstyle.php).

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, is it?