# Citing newspapers (no date) using Natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I haven't managed to produce the bibliographic entries for several newspapers that are in English and Spanish.  I am using `natbib` and the bibliography style is `aer`.  Here is the minimal code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{smercantil}

\citeauthor{nyt}

\citeauthor{mexherald}

\citeauthor{eemex}


\cite{reinhartrogoff2009}
\bibliography{overleafhelp}

\end{document}
```

The bib file is here:

```
@misc{em,
    author={{El Economista Mexicano}},
    note={Mexico City. Various issues}

}

@misc{mexherald,
    author={{The Mexican Herald}},
    note={\textup{Mexico City. Various issues}\upshape}

}
@misc{nyt,
    author={{The New York Times}},
    note={\textup{Various issues}\upshape}

}
%note={\textup{Various issues}\upshape}
@misc{smercantil,
    title={Semana Mercantil},
    howpublished={\textup{Mexico City. Various issues}\upshape},
    note={Available on http://www.hndm.unam.mx/index.php/es/}

}

@book{reinhartrogoff2009,
title={This time is different: Eight centuries of financial folly},
author={Reinhart, Carmen M and Kenneth S. Rogoff},
year={2009},
publisher={Princeton University Press}
}
```

After several more rounds of experimenting, I'm down to just 1 problem: somehow forcing the placement of certain `*.bib` entries when using `@misc`. I used `@misc` as this seemed to be the best way to place newspapers with no author and date, but the placement does not ignore the "The" (the indefinite article). So, the "The Mexican Herald" correctly goes before "The New York Times, but both should go before "Reinhart." (I'd have the same ordering issue with the "El" in "El Economista Mexicano" but it's not messing anything up in this bibliography.)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Update: I discovered a relevant post that uses an old Latex trick.  I tried this one and addresses the problem, but it's far from idea.  I have many more citations, so I'd have to impose the ordering on all of them.  I also loose the "various issues" field.  So, unless someone can suggest something better, I'll keep the current "wrong" ordering for now.  See post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160186/how-to-force-a-certain-sorting-of-two-bib-entries/160195#160195. 
 
}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure why you lose the "various issues" field, you should be able to combine this with `\noop`. Also, you don't have to impose ordering on all citations, only on the ones that do not have the correct alphabetical ordering because they start with _the_ or _el_. And with the search and replace feature of your editor, possibly combined with regular expressions, you should be able to add the `\noop` to all relevant entries relatively easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `author={{The Mexican Herald}}` you defined an author name starting with `The` and this is also used to sort the authors. To get rid of that you can use command `\noop{Mexican Herald}` to get an author name without leading `The` and used for sorting the autors. Add this command in your bib entry like

```
@misc{mexherald,
    author={\noop{Mexican Herald}{The Mexican Herald}},
    note={\textup{Mexico City. Various issues}\upshape}
}
```

or

```
@misc{em,
    author={\noop{Economista Mexicano}{El Economista Mexicano}},
    note={Mexico City. Various issues}
}
```

Please see that you have to define the command `\noop` in the preamble of your code like:

```
\newcommand{\noop}[1]{} % <=============================================
```

So with the following compilable MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{em,
    author={\noop{Economista Mexicano}{El Economista Mexicano}},
    note={Mexico City. Various issues}
}
@misc{mexherald,
    author={\noop{Mexican Herald}{The Mexican Herald}},
    note={\textup{Mexico City. Various issues}\upshape}
}
@misc{nyt,
    author={\noop{New York Times}{The New York Times}},
    note={\textup{Various issues}\upshape}
}
%note={\textup{Various issues}\upshape}
@misc{smercantil,
    title={Semana Mercantil},
    howpublished={\textup{Mexico City. Various issues}\upshape},
    note={Available on http://www.hndm.unam.mx/index.php/es/}
}
@book{reinhartrogoff2009,
  title     = {This time is different: Eight centuries of financial folly},
  author    = {Reinhart, Carmen M and Kenneth S. Rogoff},
  year      = {2009},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt]{article}%

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}
\newcommand{\noop}[1]{} % <=============================================


\begin{document}

\citeauthor{smercantil}

\citeauthor{nyt}

\citeauthor{mexherald}

\citeauthor{em} % <=====================================================

\cite{reinhartrogoff2009}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting bibliography]

Please see the correct sorting for authors with leading `El` and `The` ...

Comment: This works.  Thank you!